# Postgres query dramatically slow on prod, but very fast on local laptop

Tags: performance, postgresql, explain

I have this query http://pastebin.com/R1iLL5tn when it is run on my prod server, it takes more than a whopping 160000 ms! But when I back up the database and restore in my laptop, the same query takes just 300 ms.

Explain in local laptop: https://explain.depesz.com/s/2NmY
Explain in prod server: https://explain.depesz.com/s/hMk8

All significant settings like work_mem, cpu_tuple_cost, effective_cache_size are the same default settings in both environments..

I have tried to vacuum analyze on my prod, but it doesn't help much.

Any pointers?

Comment: There are many tools out there to analyze the server performance. Perhaps you should start with those ;)

Comment: Isn't "explain analyze" one of those?

Comment: I have just run a vacuum and analyze on the prod db, and the query time dropped significantly to 1.5 sec. Way better, yet 4 times more than my laptop.. I will continue to look for improvements..